# Getting crash in android app build with Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: android, xamarin

getting a crash in my app uploaded onto Play Store. The crash report on Google Play looks such as below. Cannot really tell what is causing the ClassNotFoundException. I have a feel that compiling with Enable Proguard causes this. I got several such errors in my previous release and finally recompiled by unchecking Enable Proguard, which stopped the occasional crashes. However, my app size then goes from 5.5 MB to 11 MB, which is a hit of a different sort.

Looking at the stack trace below, I can't tell exactly which class seems to be missing. Am I missing something obvious?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2626)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1384)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5602)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
  (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2621)
```

Comment: You have keep options to prevent renaming. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code  ProGuard reference https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/manual/usage.html#keep

Comment: Did you check you have enabled appropriate permission when you upload to play store. EG- Internet access permission

Comment: Jon Douglas' Proguard notes: https://www.jon-douglas.com/2017/07/20/proguard-notes/